# How to count categories over windows in SQL

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I've the following data structure:

```
id  flag  date
101   A     may
101   A     jun
101   1     jul
101   A     aug
101   1     sep
101   2     oct
101   3     nov
201   A     jun
201   A     jul
```

I want to create variable based off flag values and count the frequency of occurrence in SQL.

I'm trying to use window functions over id ordering by date and the resultant data set is like this:

```
id   flag_1  flag_2  flag_3  flag_else
101  2       1       1       2
201  0       0       0       2
```

Any suggestions how to achieve this on SQL

Comment: What is the significance of the `date` column (which seems to _not_ contain a `date` value...)

Comment: @Dai: The date is definitely significant, it's a time series data. I've just now shown exact dates for simplicity.

Comment: Tag your question with the database that you use.

Comment: Your target structure is not normal form. If you use the structure SQL is designed for, it's exceptionally simple; `SELECT id, CASE WHEN flag IN (1,2,3) THEN flag ELSE -1 END, COUNT(*) FROM yourTable GROUP BY id, CASE WHEN flag IN (1,2,3) THEN flag ELSE -1 END` So, why are you targeting a different structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use conditional aggregation as the following:

```
SELECT id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN flag='1' THEN 1 END) AS flag_1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN flag='2' THEN 1 END) AS flag_2,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN flag='3' THEN 1 END) AS flag_3,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN flag NOT IN ('1','2','3') THEN 1 END) AS flag_else
FROM table_name
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VamVVHcc).

If you want to apply this on a specific range of dates add a where clause, `WHERE date_ >= 'dt1' AND date_ <= 'dt2'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres 9.5 and above the below query will work:

```sql
SELECT
  id,
  flag_1,
  flag_2,
  flag_3,
  (flag_all - flag_1 - flag_2 - flag_3) AS flag_else
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      flag_1,
      flag_2,
      flag_3,
      flag_all
    FROM
      (
        SELECT
          id,
          cardinality(array_positions(array_agg(flag), '1')) AS flag_1,
          cardinality(array_positions(array_agg(flag), '2')) AS flag_2,
          cardinality(array_positions(array_agg(flag), '3')) AS flag_3,
          cardinality(array_agg(flag)) AS flag_all
        FROM
          flags
        GROUP BY
          id
      ) t
  ) t2;
```

`array_agg` converts a set of rows into an array.
`array_positions` returns an array of the subscripts of all occurrences of the second argument in the array given as first argument.
`cardinality` returns the no. of elements in an array.
See [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) for more details of the above functions.

Output:

```
 id  | flag_1 | flag_2 | flag_3 | flag_else 
-----+--------+--------+--------+-----------
 101 |      2 |      1 |      1 |         3
 201 |      0 |      0 |      0 |         2
```

This query is definitely not the most optimal or cleanest.

Comment: I'm not using Postgres and am restricted to using toad for Oracle. The functions are not supported there unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

***Oracle***
Maybe the funniest option is to use [MODEL clause](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm). You can find one of the modelings here and more common options at the end:

```sql
SELECT ID "ID",
       Sum(FLAG_1) "FLAG_1", Sum(FLAG_2) "FLAG_2", Sum(FLAG_3) "FLAG_3", Sum(FLAG_ELSE) "FLAG_ELSE"
FROM( SELECT  * FROM tbl 
      MODEL Partition By (ID)   
            Dimension By (A_DATE)   
            Measures  (FLAG, 0 "FLAG_1", 0 "FLAG_2", 0 "FLAG_3", 0 "FLAG_ELSE")
            Rules  (FLAG_1[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '1' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                    FLAG_2[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '2' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                    FLAG_3[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '3' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                    FLAG_ELSE[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE WHEN FLAG[CV()] NOT IN('1', '2', '3') THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END])
    )
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

The result with your sample data would be:

| ID | FLAG_1 | FLAG_2 | FLAG_3 | FLAG_ELSE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 201 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Or with double modeling to exclude group by:

```sql
SELECT ID, FLAG_1, FLAG_2, FLAG_3, FLAG_ELSE
FROM (  SELECT *
        FROM( SELECT  * FROM tbl 
              MODEL Partition By (ID)   
              Dimension By (A_DATE)   
              Measures  (FLAG, 0 "FLAG_1", 0 "FLAG_2", 0 "FLAG_3", 0 "FLAG_ELSE")
              Rules  (FLAG_1[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '1' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_2[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '2' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_3[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '3' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_ELSE[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE WHEN FLAG[CV()] NOT IN('1', '2', '3') THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END])
            )
        MODEL
        Partition By (ID)
        Dimension By (A_DATE)
        Measures  (FLAG_1, FLAG_2, FLAG_3, FLAG_ELSE)
        Rules   (FLAG_1['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_1)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                 FLAG_2['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_2)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                 FLAG_3['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_3)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                 FLAG_ELSE['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_ELSE)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'])
  )
WHERE A_DATE = 'SUM'
ORDER BY ID
```

This is just an example, If A_DATE column is of type DATE (which it probably is) then instead of 'SUM' put any date imposible to be found in your data (I usualy put my 100th birthday)

*The funiest part* is that it can be done **(double modeling) in one MODEL clause** in a way that you create columns with flag occurences and then you sum those occurencies for newly created columns and, finally, selecting just those summary rows....

```sql
SELECT ID, FLAG_1, FLAG_2, FLAG_3, FLAG_ELSE
        FROM( SELECT  * FROM tbl 
              MODEL Partition By (ID)   
              Dimension By (A_DATE)   
              Measures  (FLAG, 0 "FLAG_1", 0 "FLAG_2", 0 "FLAG_3", 0 "FLAG_ELSE")
              Rules  (FLAG_1[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '1' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_2[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '2' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_3[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE FLAG[CV()] WHEN '3' THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      FLAG_ELSE[ANY] = Count(1)[CASE WHEN FLAG[CV()] NOT IN('1', '2', '3') THEN CV() ELSE 'XXX' END],
                      --
                      FLAG_1['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_1)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                      FLAG_2['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_2)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                      FLAG_3['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_3)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'],
                      FLAG_ELSE['SUM'] = Sum(FLAG_ELSE)[A_DATE <> 'SUM'])
            )
WHERE A_DATE = 'SUM'
ORDER BY ID
```

The result is the same...

** Some other, **more common options** giving the same result:

```sql
--  Using Subqueries
SELECT
    ID,
    (Select Count(*) From tbl Where ID = t.ID And FLAG = '1') "FLAG_1",
    (Select Count(*) From tbl Where ID = t.ID And FLAG = '2') "FLAG_2",
    (Select Count(*) From tbl Where ID = t.ID And FLAG = '3') "FLAG_3",
    (Select Count(*) From tbl Where ID = t.ID And FLAG NOT IN ('1', '2', '3')) "FLAG_ELSE"
FROM  tbl t
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID

--  Count() Analytic Function with DISTINCT keyword (could be performance costly)
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID,
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '1' THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By ID) "FLAG_1", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '2' THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By ID) "FLAG_2", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '3' THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By ID) "FLAG_3", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG NOT IN ('1', '2', '3') THEN 1 END) OVER(Partition By ID) "FLAG_ELSE" 
FROM tbl 
ORDER BY ID
  
--  Conditional Count() - ALREADY POSTED BY  **ahmed**
SELECT 
    ID,
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '1' THEN 1 END) "FLAG_1", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '2' THEN 1 END) "FLAG_2", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG = '3' THEN 1 END) "FLAG_3", 
    Count(CASE WHEN FLAG NOT IN ('1', '2', '3') THEN 1 END)"FLAG_ELSE" 
FROM tbl 
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```

Regards...
P.S. There are 9 rows in your sample data and the sum of all flags should be 9. There is 8 in your question's result, missing one FLAG_ELSE for ID=101 (there are 3 'A' flags for 101).